# Integrating $\exp(-x^2)$ using power series

Tags: integration, power-series

I am aware of the technique to evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp(-x^2)dx$ using polar coordinates.

I recently wondered, why is it not possible to evaluate this integral using power series representation? If you express the integral using a power series, its interval of convergence is $(-\infty,+\infty)$. Why cannot we get a value closer and closer to $\sqrt{\pi}$ by using a power series?

Other functions can be integrated using a power series solution, with good approximation and precision (depending on the number of terms), in the absence of a closed form solution. Why is this integral different?

Comment: I do believe you can try it with Feyman's method.

Comment: Infinite radius of convergence is usually not a strong enough condition. The problem is the power series is not uniformly convergent,  so directly swapping the sum and integral is not justified.

Comment: How can you integrate the terms in the power series and get finite results?

Comment: It's not just $e^{-x^2}$. If you take any power series $f(x)=\sum_0^{\infty}a_nx^n$, and try to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ as $\sum_0^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_nx^n\,dx$, you just get nonsense.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you didnt answer the question. Why does this happen? Why is it not possible? Why do we get nonsense? I tried using the power series, the closest i got to the correct answer was when x = 5, the moment x > 6 (tried integers only), the values diverge.

Comment: @NinadMunshi yes, I think this is the most convincing replies so far. I am yet to receive a more convincing reply. Agree on conditional convergence of the series, hence its 'weird' convergence issues.

Comment: You don't have uniform convergence of the series on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$, just on compact subsets.  Also the infinite measure/range $\mathbb{R}$ allows "escape to infinity" that isn't possible in the finite case $[a,b]$.  So there is no reason to expect you can interchange the limit operations between (e.g. using improper Riemann integrals definition) $\lim_{M,N\to\infty}\int_{-M}^N\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{M,N\to\infty}\int_{-M}^N\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "when $x=5$". One doesn't find $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ by letting $x=5$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson When you let $F(x)$ be the power series representation of the integral, by fundamental theorem of calculus $F(5) - F(-5)$ gives a good approximation of the integral with precision of $10^{-8}$. Once you input $F(x)-F(-x)$ with $x>5$, the precision decreases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\qquad\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$$
and so:
$$e^{-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$$
the problem is that the terms alternate between positive and negative, so if you cut the series off at any arbitrary point (which is going to be small compared to the infinite number of terms). To demonstrate this point look at the graph below:
[image: graph of series]
The red line represents the actual $\exp(-x^2)$ function whilst blue is $n\in[0,5]$ and green is $n\in[0,10]$ and for your integral you want to integrate this series and then take the limit for $n\to\infty$ whilst will just accentuate any "small" error you see here

Comment: Also the comment @Ninad made is very crucial to this situation